# soap web service unusable since port 8080 is added to domain in wsdl soap address location

Tags: iis, soap, tomcat9

I have a Windows Server 2019 setup with IIS 10.

On IIS 10, I have defined a web site binded to "example.com" on port 80 and 443 with a valid SSL certificate generated by LetsEncrypt.

On this web site, I have defined rewrite rules managed by Microsoft ARR: redirection from HTTP to HTTPS and various web services redirections on Tomcat.

```
<rule name="http to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
<rule name="myAPI" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(myAPI.+)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

I have Tomcat 9 running and listening on port 8080 defined with this connector:

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
        port="8080"
        protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        relaxedQueryChars="\"
        redirectPort="8443"
        scheme="https"
        proxyport="443"
        proxyName="example.com"
        />
```

My web services use SOAP and I have a wsdl like this:

```
   <wsdl:service name="MyService">
      <wsdl:port binding="impl:MyServiceSoapBinding" name="MyService">
         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/myAPI/services/MyService"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
```

When I launch https://example.com/myAPI/services/MyService?wsdl in the browser, I can see the generated WSDL file and I have the following problem.

In the web service location, port 8080 is added to the domain, and therefore the web services are unusable.

```
<wsdl:service name="MyService">
<wsdl:port binding="impl:MyServiceSoapBinding" name="MyService">
<wsdlsoap:address location="https://example.com:8080/myAPI/services/MyService"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I don't understand what is going wrong, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

well, found it.
It's "proxyPort' and not "proxyport" in the Tomcat connector...